# Assign a variable inside a iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

After looking for a few days this answer comes close but still wont fix my problem [jQuery: How to assign a variable inside of .html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5781946/jquery-how-to-assign-a-variable-inside-of-html?rq=1)

I'm trying to get the vaule of the textbox into the scr part of a frame. I understand that from the above link that javascript must pull out the variable or it treats it as text but after trying for a few days cant get it to work. The response lands in a div on the page

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#q").bind(
      "webkitspeechchange", 
      function(evt) {
        $('.response').html(
          "<iframe width='625' height='250' border='0' src='/index.php?q=' + INPUT_HERE + ' /><br> voice search vaule:"+ $(this).val())
        .fadeIn();   
}); 
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works for me:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#q').on( 'webkitspeechchange', function(e) {
        $('#response').html('<iframe width="625" height="250" border="1" src="/index.php?q=' + $(this).val() + '" /><br> Voice search value: ' + $(this).val()).fadeIn();
    });
});
</script>

<input type="text" name="q" id="q" x-webkit-speech="x-webkit-speech">
<div id="response"></div>
```

And here is the [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Helvetian/JbFnh/)

If you want to remove the surrounding `div` you can call `$('#response').replaceWith(...` instead of `$('#response').html(...`, but be aware that successive searches won't work anymore because `#response` has been removed from the DOM.

Comment: that worked for me brilliant! I just changed $(#response) to $(.response) and all works as expected